# An interesting property of GCD, but how to prove it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I was solving a question , in which this interesting property of GCD was given in the solution of that problem : "If A = aaaa....a (m digits) and B= aaaa....a (n digits) and gcd of (m,n)=d, **then HCF of A and B = aaa....a (d digits)** "

If someone could give a hint of how to go forward in proving this that would be awesome too.  Based on my current knowledge of gcd I can't think of a starting point.

Edit:- The answers provided in the referenced links are beyond my understanding involving high level mathematics, could someone write an answer which could be comprehended by a high school student too

My knowledge :- I know what a GCD is and the Euclid Algorithm to find out gcd of 2 numbers, nothing else than this, do I need to to know something else also ? if someone could help me out it would be great

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1) near duplicate.

Comment: It's a great observation and great question and I really encourage you to try to solve it yourself... but it *is* a duplicate.

Comment: the links given as references include some math which are beyond my reach, could someone please explain it in such a manner which could be understood even by a high school student